# Settlement Permit in Germany Granted due to High Salary?

Tags: working-visas, germany, paperwork, blue-card

I am receiving an offer from a German company as a Software Engineer, and I now have 90k as salary.

I am under a normal work permit and have lived in Germany for 1 year and 4 months.

If I accept this offer am entitled for Settlement Permit in Germany due to the Salary threshold?

How does this regulation work for highly skilled workers.

**I don't have the Blue card, because my degree is not compared to a German one.**

In the website MakeIt In Germany said that Highly Qualified Professionals are entitled to live in Germany permanently: [Settlement permit](https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/visa/living-permanently-in-germany/settlement-permit#highly-qualified-professionals).
**Note how this is not the same as Blue Card.**

I have also read the page [Getting a work visa or permit for Germany](https://www.expatica.com/de/moving/visas/germany-work-visas-100900/) on Expatica.com.

Take a look at:  "Permits for highly skilled workers earning EUR 84,600+". (Update, 28.12.2020: The quote is from an older version of the article and can no longer be found there.)

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: @Gala - I have seen in both the German(make-it-ingermany) website and other web sites, like this: http://www.expatica.com/de/visas-and-permits/Work-in-Germany-getting-a-German-work-visa_100900.html

Take a look:  "Permits for highly skilled workers earning EUR 84,600+"

Comment: OK, thanks, your link helped me find where this is coming from. As far as I can tell, it refers to [§19 of the relevant law](https://dejure.org/gesetze/AufenthG/19.html). The threshold was actually lower than this between 2009 and 2012 but the provision has been scrapped entirely in 2012.

Comment: So, @Gala - would you also say that this salary threshold can be used for me getting a permanent visa? Do you think it is worth giving it a try for my case? Thanks.

Comment: Well, no, I just said the exact opposite. It was already complicated before and it's not relevant at all anymore.

Answer (score 3):

There are exceptions for refugees, blue card holders and holders of a German degree (none of which apply to you as far as I can tell) but generally speaking, you need to have been a resident for five years to apply for a *Niederlassungserlaubnis*.

There is a kind of salary threshold in that "financial security" is one of the requirements but it does not exempt you from all the other requirements (including 5-year residency) and I am not aware of any special route based on income.